# Updates to Java ConcurrentHashMap not reflecting inside lambda in Scala

Tags: java, scala, lambda

We have a java and scala inter-operable program that's internal to our org. We have interfaces from Java that's exposed and is called in scala. I have an `Optional<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>>` that's exposed from a java interface which is being used in our scala code.

Problem:

The value inside the concurrent hashmap gets updated, but the scala code doesn't reflect the changes from the update. I presume it's because the values are captured and kept as a copy rather than the reference itself, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here is the code.

```
Optional<ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>> certMetrics();
```

This is the interface method in the java code.

Now, in the scala code, the value is read and populated as

```
  if (channelBuilder.certMetrics.isPresent) {
    val certMetrics = channelBuilder.certMetrics.get
    certMetrics.forEach((key, value) => metricsGroup.newGauge(key, () => {value}, providerTag))
  }
```

This is yammer metrics which is then exposed by JMX.

However, when the underlying value in the ConcurrentHashMap is updated, the corresponding value is not reflected in the scala code.

What am I doing wrong here? If I wrap the ConcurrentHashMap in an `AtomicReference<>` (or use a map inside AtomicReference) will that be idiomatic and the right way?

Comment: I would avoid the issue entirely by using `map.get(key)` rather than the `value` in the gauge callback if you know the keys won't change.

Comment: Btw the issue would happen as well in Java if I understand it correctly. Each time you put a new value in the Map, it would be a new reference.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't the value `Long` a wrapper class, which is inside a ConcurrentHashMap, which is also a reference? 
Also, upon checking the underlying class where this comes from, the type is a `public static ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long> certMetrics = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();`
Does that make any difference?

Comment: @GaëlJ, I'm sure the value of the keys won't change at runtime, so rather than using a `value` here, is it advisable to use something like
`certMetrics.keySet().forEach(key => metricsGroup.newGauge(key, () => certMetrics.get(key), providerTag))`
instead?
Thanks again.

Comment: That's what I would do indeed. @nohup

Comment: Thank you @GaëlJ. I will try that and will keep the question open. If it works, I will get back so that you can write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @GaëlJ Apologies for the late come back and thank you for your earlier suggestion. It worked when I re-wrote as you suggested. If you'd be kind enough to write it as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept it.
On a side note, it works only if the variable is a static variable that's shared across all the instances. If it's an instance variable, the behaviour remains the same and won't get updated. Why is that? I'd be grateful if you could kindly address that in your answer as well.